# Getting object store properties without additional round-trip

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I'm using IBM FileNet CE API 5.1 and facing perfomance problem because of additional refreshing in loop with great iteration amount (25000+). Here is code sample:

```
for (Document document : documents) {
       ObjectStore objectStore = document.getObjectStore();
       objectStore.refresh(); //round-trip
       String symbolicName = objectStore.get_SymbolicName();

       ...
 }
```

The problem is, objectStore object before refresh doesn't have any cached properties at all, even object identity (if I had I could create object store cache to avoid refreshing in every iteration).

Documents may have different object stores (I'm searching through multiple object stores).

Comment: How exactly do you retrieve Document objects into the list?

Comment: I'm using SearchScope.fetchObjects(StoredSearch, ...) method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obtain the id of object store from object reference:

```
document.getObjectReference().getObjectStoreIdentity()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get object store id through EngineObjectImpl.getObjectStoreReference():

```java
GlobalIdentity objectStoreReference = ((EngineObjectImpl)object).getObjectStoreReference();
Id objectId = objectStoreReference.getObjectId();
```

Comment: EngineObjectImpl is not part of public API. Using it is not safe should be avoided.

Comment: That's true. But do you have any suggestions? API gives you only  ObjectStore object with empty cache (no properties, not even guid).

Comment: @sermolaev It depends on how you obtain the object. Please see my comment to the question.